# Source linked service should not have "service principal" as authentication method

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am trying to copy data from Azure data lake Gen2 to Azure synapse(SQL data warehouse) through Azure data factory. Following are some details:

source(ADLS) linked service authentication type: service principal
sink(Synapse) linked service authentication type: managed identity

Copy method selected : Polybase

While validating, i am getting this error: "Source linked service should not have authentication method as Service principal".
when i selected "bulk insert" copy type, it works fine.. can anyone help me understand this? is it written anywhere that for polybase we should have same authentication type for linked service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because direct copy by using PolyBase from Azure Data Lake Gen2 only support Account key authentication or managed identity authentication. You can refer to this  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse#direct-copy-by-using-polybase).

So if you want to direct copy by using PolyBase, you need change your authentication method to account key or managed identity.

There is a workaround, Staged copy by using PolyBase. You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse#staged-copy-by-using-polybase) about this.

[image]